# Battery voltage increasing while measuring (NiMH)

Tags: voltage, batteries, multimeter, nimh

I was going through conditioning for a NiMH battery pack (12 x 1.2V, 1500mAh cell) and decided to check the cell voltages. I noticed that the measured voltage, with a multimeter, increased over time. 0.001V change noticeable over periods of about 10-15s. Nothing serious, it was a minor voltage increase, I'm just curious as to the mechanism (maybe also use this phenomena?).
   [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10hVDIYr2egs8VeS3MU77-AbUauRyT6zFms9vsysAZ0Q/edit?usp=sharing/) are the voltage numbers per cell; I measured it three times and the voltage seemed to peak about 1.557V.
  So, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably some RC circuit associated with the multimeter is charging up, as it charges the very small current flow from the battery decreases, this in turn decreases the voltage drop across the internal resistance of the battery which results in an increased voltage reading.